# Как скопировать файл с устройства на пк?

Tags: java, android, android-adb

Используя данную команду в `ADB` я копирую все файлы из папки себе на пк

`adb pull data/app C:/Users/Admin/Desktop`

как можно сделать это программно?

Comment: как на счет батника с выполнением данной команды ?

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, в смысле? создать бат файл и внутри сохранить данную команду?

Comment: да, именно так. тогда не будет необходимости писать ее в консоль каждый раз - просто запускать файлик

Comment: @YuriiManziuk, и как потом мне это с java запустить, под программно я имею ввиду с java кода

Comment: я не большой специалист по java, но уверен, что есть какая-то системная функция, что позволяет выполнять команды консоли. а командой может являться запуск или батника, или уже указанна команда копирования

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему как подсказал `YuriiManziuk` создал батник, теперь нет необходимости писать ее в консоль каждый раз - просто запускаю файлик